# How to change camera focus in adobe air 14?

Tags: air, air-native-extension, air-android

Is there any way to change the camera focus in Adobe Air 14 without a Native Extension?

I am trying to find a way to control the Camera's manual focus.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, neither in AIR nor native. Most Camera API's are pretty much 'closed' to manipulation from outside, AFAIK. It has been done for some DSLR Models connected to USB, though, but in this case, AIR is working as a remote control. You don't get a live preview over AIR in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your camera DLL(if you developing this for Windows).

I know that Nikon D90 have own *.DLL's that provide full range of own API. So you need to develop ANE that will send calls to that dll and receive feedback.

Also same way you can do live preview (I done this 2 years ago).

Comment: Hello. It is posible that explain or give me a example to connect a Nikon dslr wit adober air